# NodeJS - integration tests with nightwatch selenium-standalone hang with chrome v54+

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am using Nightwatch and Selenium-standalone in my application for doing integration tests.

The integration tests worked well on my local computer until yesterday because my chrome browser has been updated to the version 54.0+.

I've reconfigured the "install" and "start" configuration script of the nightwatch integration test to avoid message "can not create session XXXXXXX" (i don't remeber the exact message).

But when I launched the tests, an chrome window opened up. It went to the requested test page, try to check that a html with css class is present but nothing happened. It stay still until I close the chrome window manually. After closing the window, an error was displayed in the console/terminal saying that the tests waited for an element with css class to be present but timeout occured...

It looks like the tests scripts was waiting for any response of the chrome browser. But the browser does not respond to the tests script. After closing manually the chrome window, i got this error message : "Timed out while waiting for element <.HeaderHome> to be present for 10000 milliseconds.  - expected "found" but got: not found".

Here is the script that install and launch the Selenium standalone server and then run the nithwatch test script :

```
var selenium = require('selenium-standalone'),
  spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
  path = require('path'),
  args = require('yargs').argv;


var installSelenium = function(done) {
  selenium.install({
    basePath: __dirname + '/../test/endToEnd/bin',
    drivers: {
      chrome: {
        version: '2.24',
        arch: process.arch,
        baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
      }
    },
    version: '3.0.1',
    baseURL: 'http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com',
    logger: function(message) {
        process.stdout.write(message + '\n');
    },
    progressCb: function(totalLength, progressLength, chunkLength) {

    }
  }, done);
}

var startSeleniumAndRunNightwatch = function(done) {
  selenium.start({
      seleniumArgs : ['-role hub'],
      basePath: __dirname + '/../test/endToEnd/bin'
    }, function(err, child) {
      if (err) return console.error('ERROR TRYING TO START SELENIUM: ', err);

      process.stdout.write('Selenium started, running nightwatch\n');

      var environment = args.env || 'default';
      process.stdout.write('Env is: ' + environment + '\n');

      var testFile = args.test;
      process.stdout.write('testFile is: ' + testFile + '\n');

      var options = ['--env', environment];
      if (testFile) {
        options = options.concat(['--test', testFile]);
      }

      nightWatchProcess = spawn(
        'nightwatch',
        options,
        {
          stdio: 'inherit'
        }
      );

      nightWatchProcess.on('exit', function() {
        if (child) {
          child.kill();
        }
      });
    }
  );
}

installSelenium(startSeleniumAndRunNightwatch);
```

Here is the relevant part of the nightwatch.json file :

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["test/endToEnd/src/tests/user", "test/endToEnd/src/tests/provider"],
  "output_folder" : "test/endToEnd/reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "test/endToEnd/src/pageObjects",
  "globals_path" : "",
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : false,
    "host" : "hub.browserstack.com",
    "port" : 80
  },
  "test_settings" : {
    "local": {
      "launch_url" : "127.0.0.1",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "127.0.0.1",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },
    "default": {
      "launch_url" : "http://hub.browserstack.com",
      "selenium_port"  : 80,
      "selenium_host"  : "hub.browserstack.com",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "browser_version" : "54.0",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },
```

Ask me if you need more precision.
Thank you for your help. ;)